# GnuHawk - codegen from custom GNU Radio component

Tags: gnuradio, redhawksdr

I am trying to generate a Redhawk component from a custom GNU Radio component. I've been unsuccessful at figuring out how to use the GnuHawk code generator plugin. Namely, what is the required starting point, and what steps in Eclipse are needed?

It seems I must create an SCA component with the Eclipse wizard, and manually add ports and properties to match the target GNU adio component. Is this right? There isn't an automatic method of doing this, starting from the GNU Radio block's code?

When I run "rhgen" manually on the SCA component, it seems to generate cpp/h files; however, I can't figure out how to invoke the GnuHawk-specific plugin..  "gov.redhawk.ide.codegen.jet.cplusplus.gnuradio"

Answer (score 2):

Gnuhawk is in its initial development stage.  This version supports a subset of GnuRadio; there are features, like complex simple property types, that both the Redhawk baseline and the Gnuhawk integration library need to have to be able to support all of GnuRadio. There's a chance that whatever block you're trying to integrate will fail to build correctly because it is missing some underlying feature. The initial set of released blocks were chosen because it was possible to supply everything that they needed.

rhgen is the command-line version of the code generators. It is meant to take an existing project and generate the associated source files. In the context of Gnuhawk, rhgen is used to re-generate component code when an update to the generators is available instead of having to do it manually through the IDE's UI.

Given the unstructured nature of GnuRadio blocks, it's not possible to completely automate the generation process. It is up to the developer to create the necessary ports and properties and use them accordingly.

The use of Gnuhawk as a stable integration platform is currently not supported. Support within Redhawk is limited to the components that have been released. Because the use of the integration library for blocks beyond those that are already released is outside the scope of support, there are no guarantees that the internal Gnuhawk API will remain stable in future releases.